# Is sending a personalized newsletter to all subscribers a bad practice in Mandrill?

Tags: php, email, mailchimp, mandrill

Normally I would use Mailchimp for sending newsletters to a large list of subscribers, but we recently decided to include personalized content in those newsletters. Mailchimp allows you to add a maximum of 30 [merge-tags](http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/how-to-use-merge-tags/html/) to a subscriber profile, ideal for using as personalized content in a newsletter.

However 30 is a fairly low limit when you want to create personalized product offers in your newsletter. Putting html in those merge-tags is no option either since they are limited to 255 characters.

It became obvious that Mailchimp wasn't an option for this, but then there's Mandrill...

We know that Mandrill is specialized in transactional mails and allows you to customize each mail that you send from head to toe. No more merge-tags and no more template limitations.

But we are not actually sending transactional emails. It's still a newsletter, only with a large part personalized content in it. And it needs to be sent to a large number of subscribers.

Would Mandrill punish us for these activities? Would this be considered "bad practice"?

If not, why still bother with Mailchimp? Why not send everything with Mandrill?

Comment: Isn't this a question their ToS and/or support should easily be able to answer you?

Comment: I already asked their technical support, but they remain vague about the use of Mandrill for this and refer to the use of merge tags for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send bulk, marketing, or newsletters through Mandrill. You should still be sure to include valid contact information and an unsubscribe link, and adhere to general best practices for list management (honoring unsubscribes, removing inactive subscribers, only sending to opt-in recipients, for example).

For developers or those who have the ability to integrate Mandrill in to their own databases or more complex list-management systems, Mandrill's a great choice. MailChimp handles lists and campaigns in certain ways that don't always make sense for every single use-case. But for a lot of companies or businesses, the process of integrating with Mandrill is more than they want (or need) when MailChimp offers the list and campaign management out of the box (particularly considering the potential costs of developing an integration specific to their needs).